# How can I simulate a (Google App Engine) High Replication datastore on a local dev machine?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have a Django app and I am trying to perform transactions over multiple types of entity groups. When I try to test this on my local dev machine I get this error:

> ERROR    2012-03-27 10:11:12,971 datastore.py:2480] Exception sending
>   Rollback: Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/usr/local/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/datastore.py", line
>   2475, in _DoOneTry   File
>   "/usr/local/google_appengine/google/appengine/datastore/datastore_rpc.py",
>   line 1984, in rollback   File
>   "/usr/local/google_appengine/google/appengine/datastore/datastore_rpc.py",
>   line 1999, in async_rollback   File
>   "/usr/local/google_appengine/google/appengine/datastore/datastore_rpc.py",
>   line 1928, in _end_transaction   File
>   "/usr/local/google_appengine/google/appengine/datastore/datastore_rpc.py",
>   line 1883, in transaction   File
>   "/usr/local/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/apiproxy_stub_map.py",
>   line 592, in get_result   File
>   "/usr/local/google_appengine/google/appengine/datastore/datastore_rpc.py",
>   line 1670, in __begin_transaction_hook   File
>   "/usr/local/google_appengine/google/appengine/datastore/datastore_rpc.py",
>   line 1184, in check_rpc_success BadRequestError: transactions on
>   multiple entity groups only allowed with the High Replication
>   datastore

What's the best workaround for this?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use --high_replication when you're launching Google App Engine from the command line. For example:

```
python /usr/local/bin/dev_appserver.py --datastore_path=/tmp/datastore app --port=9999 --high_replication
```

Answer (score 2):

The documentation refers to this: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/localunittesting#Python_Writing_High_Replication_Datastore_tests

In short, setting the policy on the datastore stub does the trick.

```
self.policy = datastore_stub_util.PseudoRandomHRConsistencyPolicy(probability=0)
self.testbed.init_datastore_v3_stub(consistency_policy=self.policy)
```